# Computational complexity (Big-O notation) of a geometrical weighted centroid among access points

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I need to compute the computational complexity of the following equations using Big-O notations:

[image]

Here, `m` is the total number of access points (perhaps the number of iterations in terms of complexity, `i` is individual access point). I learned about Big-O notation form [this](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) blog. Moreover, I found a similar question at [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_time_complexity_of_clustering_algorithms). In the above equation, `d` is a distance computed with 4 operations (multiply, subtraction, division, and power). As seen in the above equation, `w` is computed with two operations (power and division). `xw` and `yw`are computed with two operations each (multiplication and division).
Hence, I've figured out the Big-O notation of above algorithm as:

```
4*[m]+2*[m]+2*[m]+2*[m]
```

Is it correct? Can it be approximated as `O(m)` ? 
Moreover, the above algorithm (equations) is combined with next algorithm whose computational complexity is `O(N)`, `N` being the number of iterations. Here, `N>>m`. What will be the final computational complexity in terms of Big-O notation?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

The subscript `w` with `x` and `y` is just a notation. It is not the iteration.  Iteration is only `m`. Eg. `i = 1,2,3,4,5,......,m`.The two algorithms operate in a pipeline fashion. For eg., at first the algorithm with `m` iterations is operated, and the output of this algorithm is fed (as input) to next algorithm with `N` iterations. So, when `m` iterations (algorithm 1) are completed, it is followed by `N` iterations (algorithm 2). My problem is similar to two loops that are not nested and have different iterations where `N>>m`.

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
   System.out.println(i);
}

for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
   System.out.println(j);
}
```

What will be the final computational complexity?

Comment: The w subscript to x and y is hard to interpret from your explanation alone: does this indicate some kind of iteration variable?

Comment: @Vroomfondel No, the subscript `w` with `x` and `y `is just notation. It is not the iteration. It denotes a weighted centroid. Iteration is only `m`. Eg. `i = 1,2,3,4,5,......,m`.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I've updated the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your sum from `i=1` to `i=m` takes `O(m)` time. All other operations are constant, you dont have any sub-sum in sum or something like this.

About your `N` value, you did not provide enough information. We have to know how the `N` is computed or how it is related to `m`.

---

Also you should consider following constraint - can you provide some maximum value (even incredibly) big one that cannot never be reached by the numbers or equations? Usually the operation with numbers are considered constants, because they are made on 32 or 64bit numbers which always take constant time.

However if you have some equations with incredible long numbers (like hundreds of characters long or more), the size of the numbers have to be considered in complexity. (You can probably imagine that multiplying two numbers that are milion characters long takes more than doing the same with 2x2)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The output of above equation is further used in next algorithm that has N iterations. Hence two algorithms work in pipeline. For example, the output of m itirated algorithm is input to next algorithm that is itirated N times.